# Javascript regex with exception

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using RegExp in some javascript code which I'm using to replace a string that looks like this:

> [1]

With one that looks like this:

> [2]

This all works OK, however I would only like to do this, if the preceding character is not a:

> ]

So

**something[1]** *should become* **something[2]**

But

**something[1][somethingelse][1]** *should become* **something[2][somethingelse][1]**

My current code looks like this:

```
var first = 1;
var count = 2;
var pattern = escapeRegExp("[" + first + "]");
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

$(this).html().replace(regex, '['+count+']'));
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a negated character class before `[1]` part, that will match any character other than `]`. And capture it in a group:

```
var pattern = escapeRegExp("([^\\]])[" + first + "]");
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

$(this).html().replace(regex, '$1['+count+']'));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using this approach, just had to escape the square brackets in the second part too.

Answer (score 2):

What you need are [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Try this regex:

```
/(?<!\[)\[1\]/[2]/
```

Edit: Since I was just informed that JS doesn't support this, you could try negated character-classes.

```
/[^\[]\[1\]/[2]/
```

Comment: Is that so? Thanks for mentioning that, I'm going to edit my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

As a replacement for the missing lookbehind, capture the previous char in a group and put it back when replacing:

```
str = "foo[1] bar[2] baz[3][somethingelse][1]"
re = /([^\]])\[(\d+)\]/g
str.replace(re, function($0, $1, $2) { 
   return $1 + '[' + (1 + Number($2)) + ']' 
})

> "foo[2] bar[3] baz[4][somethingelse][1]"
```